# FLOPS calculation for deep architectures

Tags: neural-networks, time-complexity

Pleas guide me as I have exhausted all my efforts to do so. I need to have the FLOPS value for DeepID2+ which is an FR model and maybe a few more (DeepID, Deep Id2). No publication mentions it and I do not know how to calculate these. Is there a way simple enough for an inexperienced person like me.

The best description in the form of figure for DeepID2 and DeepID is as under. Being able to calculate FLOPS for these will do the trick for me, so please help!

[image]

The link from which these have been taken also has Keras code:

https://sefiks.com/2020/06/16/face-recognition-with-deepid-in-keras/